# Can we get page style without using UIpageviewcontoller?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios4, uipageviewcontroller

I am creating an app that have to work on iPhone3G which supports ios4..I need a bundle of images that have to be view as page style.But i came to know that ios4 doesn't support UIPageViewController..Is there a way to get that programmatically?..

If u share any tutorial or link regarding this it will be greatful...

Answer (score 1):

You cant do the same animation but you could use something similar [check this project it has its own demo](https://github.com/brow/leaves)

Please note that i had done a project similar to yours, what i did is to present different readers for ios4 and iOS5 in iOS4 i used the link i gave you, in iOS 5 i used `UIPageViewController`